# How do i use csv variables inside of a jmeter groovy script?

Tags: java, csv, groovy, jmeter

I have a test plan with a csv data set config set up like so: [CSV Data set Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfxRt.png)

My csv file looks likes: [CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ABsI.jpg)

My JSR223 Assertions looks like: [JSR223 Assertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei0C8.png)

I want to use those values in D-J for my assetions. I tried using `vars.get("phmDownloadStatus")` and `${phmDownloadStatus}` inside of the groovy script but neither gets the value from the file. How do i go about using these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the variable names inside your csv data set config. Add the variable names for each column in your csv file separated by a comma delimiter as below

[image]

Make sure to select `ture` for `ignore first line` as well if you are using headers.

Now you should be able to use these values in your JSR223 Assertion.

- [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)
- [Jmeter user manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

Answer (score 0):

1. To get variables from a CSV file first of all you need to create a
   CSV file configuration tab using Jmeter UI.
2. Then provide the source
   path of the SCV file and provide the names for variables as you
   want.

[image]

3. When you are done with the configurations window should be something similar to this. Then specify a delimiter to separate the data points for variables.
4. Then create a CSV file that aligns properly with the configurations you have defined. *(Example set of data in the CSV according to the attached config is provided here)*

> ```
> /t/3wso2.com/customers_3_1/1.0.0,3wso2.com,rkheSO1QK8DWLXKfYUJFrqXtHvAa,3bNiqxKVMAtpg9zdbcZQODP6qK4a
> /t/3wso2.com/customers_3_1/1.0.0,3wso2.com,f6inOQocRxm2qTmAkG3z9dNboOMa,CVsZlaVlg0WVlyqHc97bHQ6WCOca
> /t/3wso2.com/customers_3_1/1.0.0,3wso2.com,ZYJW0i02wSuyqlGB3WPWSvZGHYca,_cJLdQaeTo0j9gci5S2ELvaT_Yca
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks okayish, just make sure that your `J_phmDownloadStatus` and `phmDownloadStatus` JMeter Variables exist and have their respective anticipated values, you can check which variables are available for JMeter using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/)

Just make sure:

1. To declare variable names which will be 100% matching the column names in your CSV file including case of every single letter because `foo` and `Foo` are absolutely different beasts from [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) perspective
2. Don't refer JMeter Variables in Groovy scripts as `${phmDownloadStatus}` as [JSR223 sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) will cache the first occurrence and will use it for all subsequent iterations